# Are there any workarounds for this Mobile Safari box-shadow bug?

Tags: webkit, css

**UPDATE 1**: Mobile Safari for iOS 7 shows the box shadows properly on **iPhone**, but the problem is with Mobile Safari on **iPad** with iOS 7. Chrome for iOS 7 also exhibits the same behavior on iPad.

**UPDATE 2**: Here's a video demonstration of the issue: [youtube.com/watch?v=eTewrM5vIaQ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTewrM5vIaQ).

The following CSS/HTML (JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/ohErOtuM/1/)) creates a 3D box in Safari 7 for desktop, Firefox, and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .coming-back {          
        display: inline-block;          

        padding: 100px;

        background-color: rgb(31, 219, 153);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 
            15px 15px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            14px 14px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            13px 13px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            12px 12px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            11px 11px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            10px 10px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            9px 9px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            8px 8px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            7px 7px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            6px 6px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            5px 5px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            4px 4px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            3px 3px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            2px 2px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            1px 1px 0 0 #2d9a74;
      -moz-box-shadow: 
            15px 15px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            14px 14px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            13px 13px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            12px 12px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            11px 11px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            10px 10px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            9px 9px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            8px 8px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            7px 7px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            6px 6px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            5px 5px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            4px 4px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            3px 3px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            2px 2px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            1px 1px 0 0 #2d9a74;
      box-shadow: 
            15px 15px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            14px 14px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            13px 13px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            12px 12px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            11px 11px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            10px 10px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            9px 9px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            8px 8px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            7px 7px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            6px 6px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            5px 5px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            4px 4px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            3px 3px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            2px 2px 0 0 #2d9a74,
            1px 1px 0 0 #2d9a74;

        color: #fff;
        font-family: "rooney-sans",sans-serif;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 96px;        
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
            body {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }       

            .coming-back {
                padding: 50px;
                font-size: 64px;
            }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            body {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }       

            .coming-back {
                padding: 50px;
                font-size: 64px;
            }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="coming-back">
        Coming back soon!
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Similar to this:

[image: 3D Box]

However in Mobile Safari 7 (iOS 7) it doesn't render the borders at all.

Is this a know bug? Are there any workarounds for this issue? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could not reproduce this. I've opened your JSbin in both Safari and Chrome on an iPad with iOS7 and the `box-shadow` was there.

Comment: Just to make sure out iPads have the same configurations: are you using iOS 7.0.4 with an iPad 4?

Comment: @myajouri Also could you please test it in landscape mode as well? Here it renders fine in portrait mode, but not in landscape mode.

Comment: A vide of the issue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTewrM5vIaQ

Comment: I see. I didn't realize you have to zoom. Maybe you should indicate in the question ;)

Comment: @myajouri for me (iPad 4 + iOS 7.0.4), in landscape mode this issue occurs even without zooming. In portrait mode, however it happens after zooming in. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted this issue to WebKit's [bug database](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126151) as well as Apple's. It is confirmed that this is indeed a bug and Apple is aware of it. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next update to iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be strongly related to using multiple shadows. Even though I can't tell you why, it doesn't seem strange at all given the range of bugs I have seen before on Mobile Safari :)

As a workaround, I suggest using one shadow and relying on :before and :after pseudo elements to add the triangle corners that will make your shape look 3D.

```
.coming-back {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 16px 16px #2d9a74;

  /* other styles... */
}    

.coming-back:before,
.coming-back:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;      /* border width is 1/2 shadow offset */
}

.coming-back:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  border-left-color: #2d9a74;
  border-bottom-color: #2d9a74;
}

.coming-back:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-top-color: #2d9a74;
  border-right-color: #2d9a74;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/UhelOfic/2

The one thing to note is that this works better if your shadow offset was an even number (I have changed the shadow offset to `16px`).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem. I defined the border radius and it worked on ipad.

border-radius:1px